# Creating li's as horizontal connected dots

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `ul` where the `li`s are horizontally connected dots. Additionally, I want one of the dots to be larger than the rest, and still have all the dots be centered on my connecting line.

I was able to achieve this, mostly through using `line-height` to keep everything centered.

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLh4p70p/

[image]

However, I'd also like to increase the text of the larger circle. This is where things get messed up. Increasing the font size throws `line-height` for a loop, and pushes the smaller circles down so they are no longer centered. I tried fiddling with the margins but I could never get it to line up.

**Here is what it looks like with the font increased**.

http://jsfiddle.net/rLh4p70p/1/

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this? If I'd need to refactor the whole way I'm creating the circles, I'd be OK, but at the end of the day, I'd like it to be a `ul` where each `li` is a circle, and by placing a class (say `enabled`) on an `li`, it increases the size of the circle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `vertical-align: middle` for your `li`s

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/rLh4p70p/2/)

And you [can learn](https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) about inline blocks, may be useful :)

Comment: Awesome, works great. And thanks for the blog link! Pretty useful.